# Flutter VLC Player

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = VlcPlayerController.network(
    'http://jetson-nano-ip:5000/video_feed',
    hwAcc: HwAcc.FULL, // Hardware acceleration for better performance
    autoPlay: true, // Automatically start playback
    options: VlcPlayerOptions(
      options: [
        '--rtsp-tcp', // Use TCP for improved streaming stability
        '--no-audio', // Disable local audio playback (use server audio)
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I am getting two error messages within this code and not sure how to fix it.

1. There's no constant named 'FULL' in 'HwAcc'.
   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing constant, or defining a constant named 'FULL'.
2. The named parameter 'options' isn't defined.
   Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'options'.